# Is there a mistake in “Last month, I went to Singapore, where my sister is working.”?

Tags: grammaticality, sequence-of-tenses

I wrote:

> Last month, I went to Singapore, where my sister is working.

Person A said that that I made a mistake in using «is working»

but person B said that that I made a mistake in using «where» and I should have written:

> Last month, I went to Singapore, which my sister is working.

Comment: Both person A and person B are wrong, person B disastrously so. Person A may prefer 'Last month, I went to Singapore, where my sister works.', but your original sentence is better. 'The shop where my sister works' sounds fine, but this version would not be used for a place the size of a country. Also,  'the shop where my sister is working' gives a sense that she's not there permanently. // B's rewrite is totally unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Person A is wrong. There's nothing wrong with your original sentence.

> Last month, I went to Singapore, where my sister is working.

If your sister is permanently based in Singapore, then we would prefer to say `..., where my sister works`. That's because `is ...ing` is a tense normally used for transient states.

Although your original sentence **definitely is not wrong**, I could suggest:

> Last month, I went to Singapore, where my sister works.

I could add that Person B is also wrong. Observe:

> *I went to Singapore, which my sister is working.

That sentence means your sister is working Singapore. And that doesn't make sense (there may be some slang usage I don't know).